# AngularJS Factory Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use a Factory Service function in my app to add a movie to my list. I have been able to remove a movie from the list, but I am having trouble figuring out why I can't add a movie to the current list.

```js
var app = angular.module('application', []);

app.factory("MoviesService",[function(){

 var movies = [
  {title:"Avengers: Age of Ultron",rating:"PG-13",year:"2015"},
  {title:"Ant-Man",rating:"PG-13",year:"2015"},
  {title:"The Martian",rating:"PG-13",year:"2015"},
  {title:"San Andreas",rating:"PG-13",year:"2015"},
  {title:"Jurassic Park",rating:"PG-13",year:"2015"},
  {title:"Dope",rating:"PG-13",year:"2015"}

 ];

 var factory = {};

 factory.getMovies = function(){
  return movies;
 };

 factory.addMovie = function(){

  var newMovie = {
   title: movie.title,
   rating: movie.rating,
   year: movie.year  
  }

  movies.push(newMovie);

 };

 factory.removeMovie = function(movie){
  var index = movies.indexOf(movie);
  movies.splice(index,1);
 };

 return factory;

}]);



app.controller('CustomerController',['$scope','MoviesService',function($scope,MoviesService){
 $scope.movies = MoviesService.getMovies();
 $scope.removeMovie = function(movie){
  MoviesService.removeMovie();
 };

 $scope.addMovie = function(){
  MoviesService.addMovie();
 }
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app = "application">  
<div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-md-12" ng-controller = "CustomerController">
    <table class="table">
      <caption>Optional table caption.</caption>

      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Year</th>
          <th>Rating</th>
          <th>Options</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Add</th>
          <th><input ng-model="movie.title" class="form-control"></th>
          <th><input ng-model="movie.year" class="form-control"></th>
          <th><input ng-model="movie.rating" class="form-control"></th>
          <th>
            <button class = "btn btn-success" ng-click="addMovie()"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>

          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat = "movie in movies">
          <th scope="row">{{$index}}</th>
            <td>{{movie.title}}</td>
            <td>{{movie.year}}</td>
            <td>{{movie.rating}}</td>
            <td>
              <button ng-click="removeMovie(movie)" class="btn btn-danger">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
              </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    </div>
  </div>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your addMovie function doesn't have access to `movie`, so it's probably throwing an error in the console. Change this:

```
factory.addMovie = function(){
```

to

```
factory.addMovie = function(movie) {
```

and change this:

```
$scope.addMovie = function(){
    MoviesService.addMovie();
}
```

to:

```
$scope.addMovie = function() {
  MoviesService.addMovie($scope.movie);
}
```

always pay attention to console errors. I made a working plunker of this in action:

http://plnkr.co/edit/AXNhovhKrW24FLOt9KGM?p=preview

Comment: Hi wessww, your solution worked out for me. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `addMovie` function, you trying to add a movie from a `movie` variable that does not exist in this context. So you are probably getting an error there.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to do something like:

```
$scope.movie = {}; // add this 
$scope.addMovie = addMovie;   // modify to this
```

...

```
factory.addMovie = function(movie){ // add parameter movie
  movies.push(movie);
};
```

...

give that a shot.